# iText 5 resizes the page when I add a Table spanning across pages

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfptable

I have set the document size to A4 with the following code initially document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4) but when I try to add a table spanning across multiple pages it resizes the page size to 8.2x11.69. Is this the correct reason why the page is automatically resizes or am I missing something? I can provide any section of the code if someone can take a look. [image: First page is A4 and the second is 8.2x11.69 which has the table started]

updated with the suggestion.(table.setWidthPercentage(100);)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the most recent version of iText (which is iText 7), but one of the previous versions (iText 5) that sets the default width of a table to 80% of the available width of the page.

You should add the following line (assuming that `table` is an instance of `PdfPTable`):

```
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
```

Please go to the official web site for more examples, for instance to the [Cell and Table Widths](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/cell-and-table-widths) page.

Comment: Thank you for the quick  response. I am using PdfPTable and still have the same issue even after tried your suggestion. I added the updated screenshot to the question

Comment: The new screen shot already shows a significant change. Further help is impossible because you don't share any of your code. Using `document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4)` to set the *initial* page size is very strange. Developers who read the documentation set the page size in the constructor. Your allegation that adding a table changes the page size can't be reproduced, hence all readers will ignore that as a problem. **A problem that can't be reproduced is not a problem.** I am 99% that you are misrepresenting the problem. Only code can tell.

Comment: You are correct and I got confused with the A4 and US Letter size. The first page is US letter and the second is A4 that caused this issue. when I changed the second page to Letter everything worked as expected. Once again thank you for the lightning quick response. On an another note I was trying all the solutions to set the page size the code I provided I thought exclusively setting the page size  has to do the trick if the constructor way does not work.